# The growth rate (order) of a particular function

Tags: calculus, number-theory, limits

I have a function $$g(m)=m-m^{(1-1/\ln^2(m))}$$ I want to describe the limit behavior of $g(m)$ when $m$ approaches to infinity. More specifically, I need $O(g(m))$, where $O(.)$ denotes Big O notation. From my first view, $g(m)$ should be equal to $O(m)$.

At least I want to prove that $$O(g(m))>O(\sqrt{m}) \text{  as } m\to \infty$$ which means that the grow rates of $g(m)$ is larger than $\sqrt{m}$ when $m$ is large enough.

I have conducted some simulations with Matlab, and the result is right. However, is there any efficient method to identify or compare the order of a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m-m^{1-1/\ln(m)^2}=m\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\ln(m)/\ln(m)^2}\right)
=m\left(1-\mathrm e^{-1/\ln(m)}\right)=m\left(1-1+\frac{1}{\ln(m)}+O\left(\frac{1}{\ln(m)^2}\right)\right)=\frac{m}{\ln m}+O\left(\frac{m}{\ln(m)^2}\right)$$